# How to sort dataframe by a row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[7,1,9], 'y':[4,5,6],'z':[1,8,3]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

It shows:

[image]

How to sort this dataframe by row['a']:
After sort the dataframe, it might be:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to sort each row in a pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817930/fastest-way-to-sort-each-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 5):

```
In [7]: df.iloc[:, np.argsort(df.loc['a'])]
Out[7]: 
   z  y  x
a  1  4  7
b  8  5  1
c  3  6  9
```

---

`np.argsort` returns the indices one would use to sort the `a` row, `df.loc['a']`:

```
In [6]: np.argsort(df.loc['a'])
Out[6]: 
x    2
y    1
z    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Once you have those indices, you can use them to reorder the columns of `df` (by using `df.iloc`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reindex_axis` method:

```
>>> df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: df[x]['a']), axis=1)
   z  y  x
a  1  4  7
b  8  5  1
c  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `axis=1` when calling [`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html):

```
df.sort(axis=1, ascending=False)   

>>       z  y  x
      a  1  4  7
      b  8  5  1
      c  3  6  9
```

Note that `sort` is not inplace by default, so either reassign its return value or use `inplace=True`.

Comment: I think it is just sorting the column names, not the values in row a.

Answer (score 2):

In v0.19 you can sort by rows:

```
pd.__version__
Out: '0.19.0rc1'

df.sort_values(by='a', axis=1)
Out: 
   z  y  x
a  1  4  7
b  8  5  1
c  3  6  9
```