# Dataframe rows with different orders, how to sort all rows with rules accordingly?

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, data-cleaning

Solved, following the idea from this post:
[Fastest way to sort each row in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817930/fastest-way-to-sort-each-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Please also share your idea if this is achievable with R or Excel, thanks.
Data read from csv or txt, column name comes with each value.
Rows may have different orders, for example:

```
Row#4: col1 - col2 - col3 - col4 - col6 - col5 - col7

Row#5: col1 - col2 - col3 - col5 - col6 - col7 - col4

Row#6: col1 - col2 - col4 - col5 - col6 - col3 - col7

Row#7: col1 - col3 - col4 - col2 - col5 - col6 - col7
```

```
1   "colname1": 00001,  "col2": 36, "col3": "male", "col4": "MA",    "col5": "AAA",  "col6": 10.20,  "col7": 200

2   "colname1": 00002,  "col2": 37, "col3": "female",   "col4": "CA",    "col5": "BBB",  "col6": 10.21,  "col7": 201

3   "col1": 00003,  "col2": 38, "col3": "female",   "col4": "NY",    "col5": "CCC",  "col6": 10.22,  "col7": 202

4   "col1": 00004,  "col2": 39, "col3": "female",   "col4": "CA",    "col6": 10.23,  "col5": "DDD",  "col7": 203

5   "col1": 00005,  "col2": 40, "col3": "male",  "col5": "EEE",  "col6": 10.24,  "col7": 204,   "col4": "WA"

6   "col1": 00006,  "col2": 41, "col4": "GA",    "col5": "FFF",  "col6": 10.25, "col3": "male",  "col7": 205

7   "col1": 00007,  "col3": "male", "col4": "CA",   "col2": 42,  "col5": "GGG",  "col6": 10.26,  "col7": 206

8   "col1": 00008,  "col2": 43, "col3": "female",   "col4": "CA",    "col5": "HHH",  "col6": 10.27,  "col7": 207
```

Tried `df.insert` and `df.sort_values`, neither works;
may need some function to reorder cells within dataframe,
or some function can read data based on the col name.

Want all rows read into dataframe with the correct order, or dataframe cells can be adjusted accordingly:

Is this achievable with python/pandas, to get df looks like:

```
Row#1: col1 - col2 - col3 - col4 - col5 - col6 - col7

Row#n: col1 - col2 - col3 - col4 - col5 - col6 - col7
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, r tag removed; but please share your idea if this achievable with R,

Comment: It's not clear about the format of the dataset

Comment: dataset format updated a little bit, each cell/value is separated from another one by a comma; each cell is formatted as "columnname": "value".

Comment: Can you please share data in a direct manner? If csv, then just copy the top 6 (or so) rows and paste into a [code-block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) in your question. If a `data.frame`, then `dput(head(x))` (in [tag:r], since the tag is still in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, following the idea from the below post: sort by each row, then transfer it back to a DataFrame using the original shape.

[Fastest way to sort each row in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817930/fastest-way-to-sort-each-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)