# How to sort columns for each row in pandas version > 1.2?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

`sort` is deprecated so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25818117/4139143) is no longer working.

I want to sort the columns in each row i.e leave the order of the rows unchanged, but sort the columns. The below gives me a `KeyError`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 100
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, n)), columns=[f"x{i}" for i in range(n)])

df.sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist(), axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> KeyError: 'x0'
```

What needs to be given to the `by` argument for this to work? Or how can I sort the columns for each row a different way?

Answer (score 2):

If use `axis=1` it means sorting by some row index specified in `by` parameter, so if pass columns names it raise error.

Solution is use `axis=0` what is default parameter here, but it sorting first first column, then second, then next and this way to last colum:

```
df.sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist(), axis=0, inplace=True)
#same working
#df.sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist(), inplace=True)
```

If need sorting each row/ column separately then need numpy like:

```
n = 5
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, n)), columns=[f"x{i}" for i in range(n)])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1), df.index, df.columns)
print (df)
           x0        x1        x2        x3        x4
0   -0.234153 -0.138264  0.496714  0.647689  1.523030
1   -0.469474 -0.234137  0.542560  0.767435  1.579213
2   -1.913280 -1.724918 -0.465730 -0.463418  0.241962
3   -1.412304 -1.012831 -0.908024 -0.562288  0.314247
4   -1.424748 -0.544383 -0.225776  0.067528  1.465649
..        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
995 -2.220421 -1.373835  0.115825  0.389605  1.378470
996 -1.197966 -0.147205  0.286774  0.564842  0.887080
997 -0.221042  0.069370  0.192597  1.635798  2.392110
998 -2.099356 -0.657373 -0.114802  0.566772  0.683223
999 -0.848066 -0.048965  0.711411  0.808036  3.112910

[1000 rows x 5 columns]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=0), df.index, df.columns)
print (df)
           x0        x1        x2        x3        x4
0   -3.170426 -2.940389 -3.241267 -3.007632 -3.176704
1   -2.914256 -2.921350 -2.991136 -2.839079 -3.019512
2   -2.703232 -2.896255 -2.906988 -2.650970 -2.929449
3   -2.630730 -2.848543 -2.854627 -2.604214 -2.872262
4   -2.624817 -2.704392 -2.837506 -2.562334 -2.832326
..        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
995  2.759660  2.693034  2.560085  2.463242  2.620793
996  3.076860  2.868403  2.814654  2.511557  2.644343
997  3.109919  2.949094  3.112910  2.579709  2.720169
998  3.193108  2.985259  3.137749  2.601683  2.755218
999  3.926238  3.243093  3.152057  3.078881  3.852731

[1000 rows x 5 columns]
```