# how to get max 3 value from DataFrame at Axis =1

Tags: python, dataframe

after processing some data I got df, now I need to get max 3 value from the data frame with column name

```
data=[[4.12,3,2],[1.0123123,-6.12312,5.123123],[-3.123123,-8.512323,6.12313]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =['a','b','c'],index=['aa','bb','cc'])
df
```

output:

```
      a     b   c
aa  4.120000    3.000000    2.000000
bb  1.012312    -6.123120   5.123123
cc  -3.123123   -8.512323   6.123130
```

Now I assigned each value with a columns name

```
df1 = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x:x+'='+x.name)
              a     b           c
aa       4.12=a     3.0=b       2.0=c
bb  1.0123123=a    -6.12312=b   5.123123=c
cc  -3.123123=a    -8.512323=b  6.12313=c
```

I need to get the max, I have tried to sort the data frame but not able to get the output

what I need is

```
final_df
    max=1      max=2         max=3
aa  4.12=a     3.0=b         2.0=c
bb  5.123123=c 1.0123123=a  -6.12312=b
cc  6.12313=c  -3.123123=a  -8.512323=b
```

Comment: How do you exactly end up there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to sort each row in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817930/fastest-way-to-sort-each-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
data=[[4.12,3,2],[1.0123123,-6.12312,5.123123],[-3.123123,-8.512323,6.12313]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =['a','b','c'],index=['aa','bb','cc'])

# first sort values in descending order
df.values[:, ::-1].sort(axis=1)

# then rename row values
df1 = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x + '=' + x.name)

# rename columns
df1.columns = [f"max={i}" for i in range(1, len(df.columns)+1)]
```

Result as desired:

```py
    max=1        max=2           max=3
aa  4.12=a       3.0=b           2.0=c
bb  5.123123=a   1.0123123=b    -6.12312=c
cc  6.12313=a    -3.123123=b    -8.512323=c
```

Answer (score 0):

As the solution proposed by @GuglielmoSanchini does not give the expected result, It works as follows:

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data
data=[[4.12,3,2],[1.0123123,-6.12312,5.123123],[-3.123123,-8.512323,6.12313]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =['a','b','c'],index=['aa','bb','cc'])
df1 = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x:x+'='+x.name)

data = []
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # the indices of the numbers sorted in descending order
    indices_max = np.argsort([float(item[:-2]) for item in row])[::-1]
    
    # We add the new values sorted
    data.append(row.iloc[indices_max].values.tolist())
    
# We create the new dataframe with values sorted
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [f"max={i}" for i in range(1, len(df1.columns)+1)])
df.index = df1.index

print(df)
```

Here is the result:

```
    max=1      max=2         max=3
aa  4.12=a     3.0=b         2.0=c
bb  5.123123=c 1.0123123=a  -6.12312=b
cc  6.12313=c  -3.123123=a  -8.512323=b
```