# Rearrange Strings Alphabetically Across Rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to rearrange strings alphabetically across any column name which is an integer.

Example Code / Minimum Reproducible Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {

  0: ["amazon", "ebay", "paypal"],
  2: ["paypal", "amazon", "ebay"],
  3: ["ebay", "paypal", "amazon"]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# print dataframe.
print(df)
```

**Current Output:**

```
        0       1       2
0  amazon  paypal    ebay
1    ebay  amazon  paypal
2  paypal    ebay  amazon
```

**Desired Output:**

```
        0       1       2
0  amazon    ebay    paypal
1  amazon    ebay    paypal
2  amazon    ebay    paypal
```

The number of int columns isn't fixed, and is dependant on the input data. I'm pretty stumped but I've tried this code:

```
df[[0, 1]] = df[[1,0]].where(
    df[1].isin(df[0].tolist()), df[[0,1]].values)
```

(The general idea is to check if a value is found in the adjacent cell, and swap the value - but I don't know how to scale it for a dynamic number of columns - and not sure it's the best solution).

Comment: See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25817930/2476977)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin `sorted` function for each row to sort the cell values:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sorted(x)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        0     1       2
0  amazon  ebay  paypal
1  amazon  ebay  paypal
2  amazon  ebay  paypal
```

Comment: try  `df[:] = np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1)` with numpy instead

Comment: Wow, smart. Would you like to post that in an answer or shall I edit it into mine, @cs95?

Comment: the question has been closed already so feel free to make your own edits. cheers