# How to interchange the values between two columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

Suppose I am having a dataframe like:

```
 S.NO Length  Width  Height   
  1    200      100    100 
  2    250      150    150
  3    200      250    170
```

Here in the 3rd row, Width is greater than Length, So I want to interchange those two values in the dataset where the Width is greater than Length like this

```
S.NO Length  Width  Height
  1    200      100    100     
  2    250      150    150
  3    250      200    170
```

Is it possible in pandas or if there is no solution for this, what is the best case to implement this?

Comment: One approach is to sort the rows of the subframe; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25817930/2476977)

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try with `np.sort` then assign

```
df[['Length','Width']] = np.sort(df[['Length','Width']].values, axis=1)[:,::-1]
df
Out[326]: 
   S.NO  Length  Width  Height
0     1     200    100     100
1     2     250    150     150
2     3     250    200     170
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @Ben Grossmann can do that with the following

```
df[["Width", "Length"]] = np.sort(df[["Width", "Length"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.loc` with a condition and a list of the columns:

```
cond = df['Length'] < df['Width']
cols_to_switch = ['Length', 'Width']
df.loc[cond, cols_to_switch] = df.loc[cond, cols_to_switch[::-1]].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   S.NO  Length  Width  Height
0     1     200    100     100
1     2     250    150     150
2     3     250    200     170
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's just two columns, here's an approach without a sort (or numpy).

```
idx = df[df['Length']<df['Width']].index
df.loc[idx,['Length','Width']] = df.loc[idx,['Width','Length']].values
```

---

Full code:

```
s = '''S.NO Length  Width  Height
  1    200      100    100     
  2    250      150    150
  3    200      250    170'''
data = [line.split() for line in s.splitlines()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:],columns = data[0]).astype(int)
idx = df[df['Length']<df['Width']].index
df.loc[idx,['Length','Width']] = df.loc[idx,['Width','Length']].values
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   S.NO  Length  Width  Height
0     1     200    100     100
1     2     250    150     150
2     3     250    200     170
```