# Converting pd.Series of lists to multi-column DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given Pandas `Series` of lists where all lists have the same length `N`. How can I reshape it into a `DataFrame` with `N` columns (keeping the index)?

For example, given

```
s = pd.Series([[1, 10, 0.1], [2, 20, 0.2], [3, 30, 0.3]], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

>>> print(s)
a    [1, 10, 0.1]
b    [2, 20, 0.2]
c    [3, 30, 0.3]
dtype: object
```

I want the code to produce `DataFrame` looking like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10, 0.1], [2, 20, 0.2], [3, 30, 0.3]],
            index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['X', 'Y'])

>>> print(df)
   X   Y    Z
a  1  10  0.1
b  2  20  0.2
c  3  30  0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(s, index=s.index, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

Output:

```
   X   Y    Z
a  1  10  0.1
b  2  20  0.2
c  3  30  0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself at the end. The following code does the job:

```py
pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index, columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```